# Getting a map and collectors error in kotlin function

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to convert this java function to kotlin.

```
        List<Long> creatorIds = polls.stream()
                .map(Poll::getCreatedBy)
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<User> creators = userRepository.findByIdIn(creatorIds);
        Map<Long, User> creatorMap = creators.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, Function.identity()));

        return creatorMap;
    }
```

I end up with the following:

```
fun getPollCreatorMap(polls: List<Poll>): Map<Long?, User?>? {
        // Get Poll Creator details of the given list of polls
        val creatorIds: List<Long?> = polls.stream().collect(Collectors.toList())
            .map(Poll::getCreatedBy).distinct()
        val creators: List<User?>? = userRepository!!.findByIdIn(creatorIds)
        val creatorMap: Map<Long?, User?> = creators!!.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, Function.identity()))
        return creatorMap
    }
```

However on the line

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getId, Function.identity()))
```

I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
((User?) → Long?)!
Found:
KFunction1<User, Long?>
```

Comment: You don't need `stream()` in kotlin. The [collections](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) class in kotlin provides all methods you need. (e.g. [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html), [distinct](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html), [toMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-map.html)).

Comment: This suggests the top part of the function is also wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `stream()` in kotlin. The [collections](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) classes in kotlin provides all methods you need. (e.g. [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html), [distinct](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html), [toMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-map.html)). Here is the kotlin way to write your function:

```
fun getPollCreatorMap(polls: List<Poll>): Map<Long?, User?>? = polls.map{it.createdBy}.distinct().let{ creatorIds ->
    userRepository?.findByIdIn(creatorIds)?.map{
        Pair(it.id,it)
    }.toMap()
}
```

I don't know the nullability of your data so I just leaves them all nullable. If you know the nullability, you should try to make the code as exact as possible.

Comment: yes, I reworked. Thank you for helping out and explanation as well.

Comment: Shorter version: `findByIdIn(creatorIds)?.associateBy { it.id }`